# Ansible, right way to enable EPEL: yum_repository vs yum?

Tags: yum, ansible

Ansible seems to document two ways to add EPEL [one with the `yum_repository_module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html)

```
yum_repository:
  name: epel
  description: EPEL YUM repo
  baseurl: https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/
```

and one with the [`yum` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html)

```
name: install EPEL repo
yum: name=epel-release state=present
```

Which of these is preferable?

Comment: RE: your second option - The 'epel-release' .rpm is not a standard package across all Linux distros, or even across Enterprise Linux derived distros. AFAIK it only exists in CentOS, so installing via yum the "epel-release" package is not a good practice for portable code. As others have said, follow the proper documentation on the EPEL site. An important and often overlooked fact of Automation is if one doesn't know what the commands are really doing under the hood, automating the tasks will be harder to properly achieve and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are only examples in the documentation. Basically they do the exact same thing except that with the second, you have a trace of a yum package installed to enable the repo where in the first you only end up with the relevant .repo file.

I use the second option on most of my clients networks since they are very often using an internal mirror to save bandwidth and we have to use a custom url. But in this case you also have to deal with the gpg keys (download them locally or reference them by uri). You don't have to cope with that at all when using the rpm package to install the repo (and you get upgrades through yum if anything changes).

So installing through yum is the easiest. For best good practice, I would not blindly trust ansible documentation examples anyway, but rather the [official EPEL site](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) which is referencing installation through yum.

Answer (score 3):

Neither solution worked for me on an a1.large instance running Amazon Linux 2
What I did was

```
- name: Ensure epel repo present
  yum:
    name: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
    state: present

  become: true
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me:

```
name: Install EPEL repo
yum:
  name: epel-release
  state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Being new to Ansible, I struggled with syntax indentation.

Here's what worked for me in Rocky Linux 9 and Ansible 2.13.3
using a script to install to all target nodes:

```yaml
- name: Install epel package
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Install package epel-release
    yum:
      name: epel-release
      state: present
```